# How do I make a single swarm plot using two different data frames?

Tags: pandas, ipython, swarmplot

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

df1:

```
value 
1.2
2.2
3.3
4.3
3.1
2.1
....
```

I have another dataframe that looks similar but with different values:

df2:

```
value 
1.0
1.2
1.3
2.9
3.1
1.9
....
```

I want to make a swarm plot so that I have both df1 and df2 on the same plot, so I can directly compare the two. Ideally I would also like some sort of t-test between the two. Can I do this in pandas?

Comment: look into [seaborn.swarmplot()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do it this way by concatentating dataframes together and reshaping:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, keys=['df1','df2']).stack(0)

df3 = df3.reset_index(level=1)

sns.swarmplot(x='level_1',y='value', data=df3)
```

Output:
[image]

And T-Test:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

ttest_ind(df1['value'],df2['value'])
```

Output:

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=1.3828776509907013, pvalue=0.1967994944161096)
```

Comment: for my actual data I get the following error when trying to concatenate: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: Instead of `df3 = df3.reset_index(level=1)`, try `df3 = df3.reset_index()`

Comment: when I used sns.swarmplot I get: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'swarmplot'. I have imported it like: import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns